# Sort data by time slot in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have to sort data coming from the server dynamically by differents fields. It is working perfectly with all the fields except by time slot field. I have to sort data by time slot field in ascedening order, the problem is that the time slot is string e.g: "09:00-09:59".

My sorting function is:

```
function sortArray(array: any[], direction: string, extractor: (any) => any): any[] {
  return array.sort((e1, e2) =>
    (direction === 'asc' && extractor(e1) > extractor(e2)) || (direction !== 'asc' && extractor(e1) < extractor(e2))
      ? 1
      : -1
  );
}
```

How can I fix it? If anyone know then please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: The optimal solution will depend on the flexibility of timeslots - are they always just one hour? The approach to a solution would involve converting the beginTime and endTime to timestamps (like unixtime). Then you can compare beginTimes and endTimes of two timeslots against each other.

Comment: As your "time slot" are in the way 00:00-00:00 is a simple sort like a string: `return array.sort((a,b)=>a>b?direction=='asc'?1:-1:a<b?direction=='asc'?-1:1:0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **sortArray** function is fine. You have to check sort.active and sort.direction are updating correctly.

Try like this:

```
  console.log('this.sort.active', this.sort.active);
  console.log('this.sort.direction', this.sort.direction);
```

And If they are not updating then this is the problem. Then revise your logic of updating these things.